# FPGA, reloadable, programmable FIR or IIR filter

Tags: filtering, vhdl, signal-processing, zynq

I need help with FIR Filter. Standard filter in Vivado (FIR compiler) with fixed coefficients works. But I need to be able to change the coefficients. FIR compiler allows it, but do not know how to program (I tried to write something, but I do not know if it's good). I also tried FIR filter FDATool with a processor interface. It also works somehow (filter), but I do not know how to send and timing coefficients (code that generates coefficients I have.). I need help with it quickly. If anyone know how to set it up so I'll be very happy. Searching and testing, I spent a lot of time, but the demonstration of how to set FIR filter (in c) I spotted. I've been pretty desperate. I do not know what to do. Anyone familiar with this topic and would help me? I was very grateful.

How can I do it?

Thomas.

Comment: This is not really a specific coding question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to achieve under which conditions and give an example of what you want/have tried.

Comment: I am doing SDR radio. 12bit ADC, 1MSPS work. Next stage is complex multiplier to create  I/Q signals, work to. After this mixing i need FIR filter for tuning. For demodulating I use CORDIC. Audio output 32bit 48kSPS work to. Between CORDIC and audio output is CIC for decimation (about 21-25 rate) ADC>I/Q>FIR>CORDIC>CIC>Audio

Comment: Here are my some images and c code http://mujweb.cz/t.dubina/files/pub/

Comment: demodulating_cordic_am_gen - Generate AM signal in FPGA and demodulating. fir_gpio_connect - connect reloadable FIR with CPU and program in c. input_without_fir - demodulating all input signal from ADC, no tuning filter provided.

Comment: Your question is very vague. It seems you want us to go though all your code on an external link and magically see what is going wrong. Do you want us to build a system for you? I do that for a job. You could contact my boss ;) No, but seriously: we can only answer specific questions about code here, not solve such big problems.